# Do unused properties in a metal struct hurt performance

Tags: fragment-shader, metal

Suppose I have the following struct in a `.metal` file:

```
struct VertexOut{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 a;
    float2 b;
};
```

This struct is the `[[ stage-in ]]` input for my fragment shaders. Now some of my shaders use `b` and some do not. Is this hurting performance at all, meaning should I create another struct without `b` for the shaders that do not need it?

Comment: I would have thought that the only adverse affect an unused property would have is that it's wasted memory that will need to be copied to the buffer. Other than that I can't see an issue with it. Take this with a pinch of salt though as I'm not 100% on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your usage. There will be a memory bandwidth performance hit but it will be fairly small.
If you were outputting a full screen of pixels using this shader and were bandwidth limited, removing the unneeded float2 *may* help.

However, there is often a performance hit in changing shaders, so you are possibly getting a performance benefit by not needed to change fragment shaders which quite possibly outweighs any losses.

One suggestion I would make is to some change a and b to be `float4 a_b` and access it with `a_b.xy` and `a_b.zw`. Registers are aligned to 16 bytes, so this will save you space. Take this example:

`struct X
{
 float4 position;
 float2 a;
 float2 b;
};
struct Y
{
 float4 position;
 float2 a;
};
struct Z
{
 float4 position;
 float4 a_b;
};`

In the above case, X will use 48 bytes (there are 3 registers of 16 bytes each), whereas Y or Z is only 32 bytes (there are 2 registers). So using Z would potentially give you the best of both worlds.